# Symfony Write to sfGuard Table

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfguard

I know it's not ideal, but I have a few extra fields on the sfGuard User table and I would like to write to it from another module.   There is a specific field that is a simple integer but I would like it to -1 each time they perform a specific task.   Here is what I tried.   I don't get an error message but it also doesn't write the number to the table.

```
  public function executePublish(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();
    $times = ($this->user->getTimes() - 1);
    $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->setTimes($times);
  }
```

This is the "Publish" action for a different module.  Am I doing this wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't maked an INSERT to the database by `setTimes($times)`
you have to call `save()` method after setting all values of object.

It should look like this:

```
 public function executePublish(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();
    $times = ($this->user->getTimes() - 1);
    $this->user->setTimes($times);
    $this->user->save();
  }
```

Comment: Works awesome.   Thanks for that.   I'm not sure how I missed that.   :)